# Duplicate elements in #each Svelte

Tags: javascript, arrays, svelte

I have a component on related posts on the Svelte website. It works, but the problem is that it duplicates the articles in the block. That is, for example, if I have three identical tags contained in two articles, then in each of these articles another article in the related posts block will be listed three times.

```html
<script>
    import { getMarkdownPosts } from '$lib/utils/getPosts'

    let posts = getMarkdownPosts()

    export let currentPostTitle, currentPostTags

</script>

{#await posts}
    Loading...
{:then posts}
   Related posts
    <ul>
        {#each posts as {slug, meta: {title, tags, published}}}
            {#if published}
                {#if currentPostTitle != title}
                    {#each tags as tag}
                        <!-- {#if index === 1 } -->
                            {#if currentPostTags.includes(tag)}
                                <li><a href="/blog/{slug}"><h4>{title}</h4></a></li>
                            {/if}
                        <!-- {/if} -->
                    {/each}
                {/if}
            {/if}
        {/each}
    </ul>
{/await}
```

How can I change this code so that this does not happen?

Comment: erm... is there actually a reason to loop over the tags there? What did you expect the result to be if multiple tags match? obviously the code does exactly what you wrote it to do, but it's unclear what you instead expected it to do.

Comment: Very clever) Can you help me better?

Comment: Currently no, i need more information.

Comment: Mayby you want check the tags array intersection at the same time you are checking for the title?. something like (untested) `{#if currentPostTitle != title && currentPostTags.filter(value=>tags.includes(value)).length}` and then remove the loop over tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about it and rewrote the component. It's working fine now

```
<script>
    import { getMarkdownPosts } from '$lib/utils/getPosts'
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    let posts = []
    let relatedPosts = []

    export let currentPostTitle, currentPostTags

    onMount(async () => {
      posts = await getMarkdownPosts()
      filterRelatedPosts()
    })

    function filterRelatedPosts() {
      relatedPosts = posts.filter(post => {
        // Exclude the current post and duplicates based on tags
        return (
          post.meta.title !== currentPostTitle && post.meta.published &&
          currentPostTags.some(tag => post.meta.tags.includes(tag))
        )
      })
    }
  </script>

  {#if relatedPosts.length > 0}
    Related posts
    <ul>
      {#each relatedPosts as { slug, meta: { title } }}
        <li><a href="/blog/{slug}"><h4>{title}</h4></a></li>
      {/each}
    </ul>
  {:else}
    No related posts found.
  {/if}
```